# Looking for density estimator with time complexity $< \mathcal O(n^2)$

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, density-function

I am doing univariate non-parametric density estimation on a dataset $D$, and I want to

1) Train a density estimator on $D$

2) Compute the estimated density at each point in $D$

These two operations should have an aggregate time complexity $< \mathcal O(n^2)$, and the PDF estimate should be differentiable.

An $\mathcal O(n)$ time complexity of the aggregate process is possible with the histogram estimator. However, the PDF estimate is not differentiable.

The Gaussian kernel density estimator gives a differentiable PDF estimate. However, the time complexity of the aggregate process is $\mathcal O(n^2)$. With Gaussian KDE, density estimation of a single point is $\mathcal O(n)$, so density estimation of all points in the dataset would be $\mathcal O(n^2)$. Thus this method does not have an aggregate time complexity $< \mathcal O(n^2)$.

Does there exist a density estimator that would satisfy both conditions?

EDIT:

I found a way to have an aggregate time complexity of $\mathcal O(n)$ with Gaussian KDE. See the following link...

http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~lzhao/papers/MyPublication/Fast_jcgs.2010.pdf